# Gain admin access on Windows 8.1 Enterprise with Bitlocker enabled

Tags: windows-8.1, administrator, bitlocker

I'm supporting a user whose company went bust and was allowed to keep his laptop. He has a domain user account which he can login to and has been using his computer fine. But he needs to gain admin access in order to properly use the computer which includes licensed software. As the company has gone there is no chance of getting it done by them and a wipe will lose his access to the software.

The computer is bitlocker-protected so I can't attempt the usual password resets without the recovery key. Is there any way to export the recovery key without admin access? Or to  elevate to admin?

Lenovo, Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Comment: “Is there any way to export the recovery key without admin access?” - Far easier to just disable BitLocker than export the key, and exporting the key, wouldn’t let you do anything unless you have the recovery key. The key used to encrypt the files and the recovery key are two entirely different things. Is there a reason you don’t just reinstall Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound Reason: free software ;) Also, won't an Enterprise Win install eventually time out without being able to phone the mothership domain controller?

Comment: @Ramhound don't think you can deactivate bitlocker as non-admin.

Comment: Keeping Win8 is a dead end, anyway. What software would be worth the trouble to keep? If it were MS Office, there's free LinreOffice and OpenOffice. If it were an Oracle DB, that's available free for developer... usw.

Comment: @Ramhound If I could disable bitlocker then that does the same thing. So can you disable bitlocker without admin access?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Solidworks 2017 - they have the license key I believe, but no guarantee that a deactivation (for reactivation on another device) will be possible without admin. If full access can be gained, the license can be potentially transferred - of course, if they can get hold of the installer, which isn't directly available any more...

Comment: @Tetsujin it may be complaining about activation but is still working fine.

Comment: It might be working today but without being activated you that will be short lived. Avoid malware claiming to be activation servers (KMS) for Enterprise editions of Windows. It will work for about 180 days without negotiation with a KMS. If you can disable BitLocker protection you should.

Comment: As it is Windows 8 it might be possible to use an exploit to elevate privileges to root. ( -> MetaSploit).

Answer (score 0):

1st make sure that Bitlocker is used with a TPM at all (in transparent mode or with PIN entry). If it is not, but you use a Bitlocker password, becoming admin is easy: you may mount the drive offline from a booted windows setup and its command line with manage-bde.exe and modify its registry - in that case, please ask for details.
But if a TPM is being used, which I assume, you would need to abuse an unpatched security hole in order to gain admin privileges and then you will not only be able to retrieve the recovery key or Bitlocker, but modify the admin group membership as well.
If you don't find such a hole, you would need to do so-called TPM-sniffing or perform a cold-boot-attack against the Bitlocker key.

Comment: Thanks. It's a Lenovo business laptop so I'm fairly sure TPM will be on. It sounds to me at this point the best option is to for the user to either keep it as-is and suck up the issues they're having, or get me to wipe and fresh-install the computer, as I don't think they'll want to pay me the time to thoroughly investigate and run a security hole attack if there's not an easy straightforward one for me to use.